# Maven Test Package Scope

Tags: java, maven

**Introduction:**
Though the title looks duplicate to other stackoverflow questions i've already read it and not similar question.

**Background:**
I have created a maven project with `package x.y.z` under `src/main/java` and lot of classes inside of it let say classes A-Z. Only class A is defined as `public class`. i have created another `package a.b.c` and the only class that is accessible is `class A` as expected.

**Question:** But why Test classes under src/test/java able to access all java classes inside `package x.y.z` even classes defined as non public access modifier? How will i make this inaccessible to Test classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Test Classes are in the same package, which is `x.y.z`. That is why they are directly accessible. It is just that, directory structure is different for test class not the base package, which they are part of.

Check you test classes package declaration must be `package x.y.z`.

When we write the test cases, you always use the package to which the code class belong.